# How to display different colours for groups in plot()?

Tags: sorting, plot, colors, subset

I want to plot my data with different colours for different groups without ggplot2 or lattice. Is it some sort of problem that subset in plot doesn´t not work with factor as character?

In the dataset are two Variables and a Factor. The Variables are numeric and the Factor (e.g. apple, pear) is saved as a character. When I try to plot subset by the factor, there are no points to see. Without the subset there are. 
If I transform my Factor into numbers instead of words (apple = 1, pear =2), it works to colour the points differently. But then my legend to show fails.

```
A<- data$Variable1
B<- data$Variable2
C<- data$Factor

plot(B,A, pch=16, col=c("green3","black")[C], cex=.5, lwd=2, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", ann=FALSE)
legend(x="topleft",legend=levels(C), pch=16, col=c("green3","black"))
```

The plot should have points of different colour chosen by factor and a legend explaining the colour.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself, it´s factor().
So the correct code looks like this

```
plot(B,A, pch=16, col=c("green3","black")[factor(C)], cex=.5, lwd=2, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", ann=FALSE)
legend(x="topleft",legend=levels(factor(C)), pch=16, col=c("green3","black"))
```